# Android, add a condition to my button (SMS app)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, broadcastreceiver

I have made an SMS app (I'm a newbie). When the user press a button a message will be sent to a number where the user types in. That goes okay! but when there there is no number (Textview is empty) the app crashes. So i tried adding a condition to when the Textview is empty send a Toast, if it is not empty send message, here my code. I tried diffrent ways but the body in Else is activated anyway? Hope someone can help me :).

sendSMSa2 is my button.
nyanumtxt is where the number is.

```
sendSMSa2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(View v) {


                                                      if(nyanumtxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Number chossen",
                                                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                                                     } else {


                                                     String myMsgrela1 = a2txt.getText().toString();
                                                     String theNumberr = nyanumtxt.getText().toString();
                                                     sendMsg(theNumberr, myMsgrela1);
                                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message sent!",
                                                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                 }

                                             }
                                             }
                );
```

log cat

```js
11-18 21:05:01.505 22083-22083/user.smsgsm20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: c.timno.smsgsm20, PID: 22083
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1478)
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:881)
                                                                      at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:181)
                                                                      at c.timno.smsgsm20.Fragment.sendMsg(Fragment.java:359)
                                                                      at c.timno.smsgsm20.Fragment.access$000(Fragment.java:34)
                                                                      at c.timno.smsgsm20.Fragment$1.onClick(Fragment.java:184)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18475)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nyanum text contains blank spaces that's why else condition is executed.
try this

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nyanumtxt.getText().toString().trim())){
//your code
}
else{
//your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! gonna read more about .trim(). Perfect! Feels great that i atleast was on the right path on my code :D .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nyanumtxt.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. I still get crash, my log highlights,  "sendMsg(theNumberr, myMsgrela1);" .. :(

Comment: Can you post your logcat ?

Comment: Updated it, it works well when a numbers is typed.